# Evaluating binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

$$\binom{1}{0},\binom{1}{1},\binom{1}{2}$$
 What does this mean, and how do I achieve an numerical value when trying to solve a proof or problem in this form?

Comment: Evaluate means find the numeric value, as in evaluate $1+1$ (where you are supposed to find $2$). You might want to give us the definition of $\binom nk$ that you are working from; if not there is no sure way to answer. In any case, the definition should allow you to work out these cases yourself by just looking what it is saying.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, in general, $\binom{n}{k}$  is a number with value = the count of ways $k$ objects can be selected out of $n$ objects (when we are not interested in the order of selection, but just in the set of elements that are chosen).

Respectively:

- $\binom{1}{0} = 1$ since there is only one way to select 0 elements out of 1 - just do not select anything.
- $\binom{1}{1} = 1$ too, since we must just select the only element we have. We know also that $\binom{1}{1} = \binom{1}{0}$, because $1=1-0$.
- $\binom{1}{2} = 0$ since we cannot select 2 elements out of 1, at all. In general, $\binom{n}{k} = 0$, if $k>n$ or $k<0$.

Comment: is $1 \choose 2$ equal to $0$ or is it "not defined"?

Comment: @Thanassis I think the fact that $\binom{n}{k}$ is not defined for $k>n$ implies that it is zero, which is what is seen in most books.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, it's not that it's not defined.  It's very well-defined: How many ways can you choose two distinct items out of a singleton set?  The answer is $0$, so it *is* defined.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of ${n}\choose{k}$ is $\frac{n}{k!(n-k)!}$. To use them numerically you can simply compute those values. Notice that there's som cancellation between the numerator and denominator so you could instead compute:

$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k + 1)}{k!}$ or $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(k + 1)}{(n-k)!}$

Comment: By which we obtain $\dbinom 1 2=\dfrac{1!}{2!~(-1)!}$ and not help the OP at all .  The formula is only valid for $0\leq k\leq n$ for a reason.

Comment: That is **not the definition**, but a formula to compute them when ($n,k\in\Bbb N$ and) $0\leq k\leq n$. The basic definition is that $\binom nk$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of a (fixed) $n$-element set.

Answer (score -2):

An expression for ${n}\choose{k}$ that you can use to compute it is $\frac{n}{k!(n-k)!}$.

The actual interpretation of the values is:

1. $\binom{1}{0} = 1$ means there is only one way to select 0 elements out of 1element
2. $\binom{1}{1} = 1$ means we one element and select the only element we have.
3. $\binom{1}{2} = 0$ means we cannot select 2 elements out of 1 so 0

Comment: Whats wrong with it

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but OP doesn't seem to know the definition and you are merely shouting facts through text without providing justification.

Comment: Ok i am trying to make it better

Comment: Is it ok now to make them understand

Comment: Remove the opening 2 lines, that's not the definition, and it is of no use here. The remainder is fine.